# How to make blood splat appear when bullet hits enemy

Tags: python, pygame

I have a game where enemy soldiers come down the page and you have to shoot them, then you get an overall score at the end. I have a picture of a blood splat that I want to appear when an enemy is shot. How would I do this? I haven't tried anything, apart from defining blood splat and trying to call it when I shoot an enemy, but I wasn't sure how to exactly do that.

Code, if anyone's interested:
You may want to take a look at the `for bullet in bulletList` section

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * 
import random

# define some colours
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        # call the parents (sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('Cartoon army guy 2.gif').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 

    def update(self):

        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        self.rect.x = pos[0] # set the player position to the mouse on the screen

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('bullet 2.gif').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        # this is for moving the bullet up the screen
        self.rect.y -= 5

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('enemy soldier 2.gif').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += float(1.5)



pygame.init() # initialise pygame

# set the window width and height for the screen
windowWidth = 600
windowHeight = 600

# make the screen
thescreen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
# create the caption
pygame.display.set_caption('Shooter!')

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)

background = pygame.image.load('dry-desert-wasteland.jpeg').convert()

# set the score to 0
score = 0

# sets how fast the game updates the screen
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

allSpritesList = pygame.sprite.Group() # make a group with all sprites in it

enemySpriteList = pygame.sprite.Group() # make a group of sprites with just enemies in it

bulletList = pygame.sprite.Group() # make a group of sprites for just bullets

player = Player() 
allSpritesList.add(player) # add player to the group of all sprites


player.rect.y = 540 # set the player y value to 540 (can't move up or down)



# create the enemies --------------------
for i in range(200):
    enemy = Enemy() 

    enemy.rect.x = random.randrange(0, windowWidth)
    enemy.rect.y = random.randrange(windowHeight - 7000, windowHeight - 650)

    enemySpriteList.add(enemy)
    allSpritesList.add(enemy)

    if enemy.rect.y > 610: # if enemy goes beyond 610 pixels of the screen, remove it
        enemySpriteList.remove(enemy)
        allSpritesList.remove(enemy)

# ------------MAIN LOOP--------------
running = True
while running == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: # if person presses mouse down key
            bullet = Bullet() 


            # set the bullet rect.x and rect.y equal to that of the player
            bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x 
            bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y


            allSpritesList.add(bullet) # add bullet to all sprites list
            bulletList.add(bullet) # add bullet to bullet group

    allSpritesList.update() # update the sprite list so everything works


    for bullet in bulletList:
        # collision between enemies and bullets
        enemyCollision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, enemySpriteList, True) 
        for enemy in enemyCollision:
            bulletList.remove(bullet) # remove bullet if it hits enemy
            allSpritesList.remove(bullet) # remove bullet from allspriteslist if hits enemy
            score += 1 # add 1 to the score
            print( score )




        if bullet.rect.y < -5: # if bullet goes beyond 5 pixels of the screen, remove it
            bulletList.remove(bullet)
            allSpritesList.remove(bullet)

    thescreen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    allSpritesList.update() # update all sprites (instead of having to update player, enemy
    # and bullets
    allSpritesList.draw(thescreen) # draw all sprites to the screen

    pygame.display.update() # update the screen with what we've provided

    clock.tick(60) # set FPS(frames per second) to 60 
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a `Player` method `Hit` (or BulletHit, whatever you prefer) which will blit the splatter to your Player sprite. This ensures that you have the player's position details to blit them properly.

Also, you can simply do `while running:` rather than `while running == True`.

Comment: Ahh yes! I would call it in the enemyCollision? Thanks. And haha! I didn't think of that :p

Comment: Yup, call it in the `enemyCollision` loop. Your welcome :) Btw, great project, I would love to play it!